# How to know items which are fully visible in the view port of a lazy row in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I have a lazy row that contains items. Now I want to make an API call for the items which are fully visible in the viewport whenever the user scrolls the lazy row.

I have tried the following code:

```
    listState = rememberLazyListState()
    LaunchedEffect(listState){
    snapshotFlow { listState.firstVisibleItemIndex }
    .collectLatest{
    Log.d("printed Item",  listState.firstVisibleItemIndex.toString())
    }}
```

The problems with this code are:

1. Even though the 2nd item occupies the viewport, it will not be printed unless the 1st item is fully invisible.
2. For the tablets, due to their large screen sizes, only the API call is made for the first visible item even though there are 2 visible items on the screen. Please refer to the screenshots.

When the first item is partially visible and 2nd item is fully visible
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5QcB.jpg

When the 2nd tile is fully visible and the first tile is completely invisible
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rmiQ.jpg

For the tablets where 2 items are completely visible
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYRTI.jpg

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve my issue?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All info about visible items is available in `state.layoutInfo`. To check wether the item is visible you need to compare first and last item positions(all other items for sure are gonna be visible) according to viewport size.

To initiate recomposition only for changed cells, you can again use `derivedStateOf` within `item` to convert the indexes to a specific boolean state.

```
val state = rememberLazyListState()
val fullyVisibleIndices: List<Int> by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        val layoutInfo = state.layoutInfo
        val visibleItemsInfo = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
        if (visibleItemsInfo.isEmpty()) {
            emptyList()
        } else {
            val fullyVisibleItemsInfo = visibleItemsInfo.toMutableList()

            val lastItem = fullyVisibleItemsInfo.last()

            val viewportHeight = layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset + layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset

            if (lastItem.offset + lastItem.size > viewportHeight) {
                fullyVisibleItemsInfo.removeLast()
            }

            val firstItemIfLeft = fullyVisibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull()
            if (firstItemIfLeft != null && firstItemIfLeft.offset < layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset) {
                fullyVisibleItemsInfo.removeFirst()
            }

            fullyVisibleItemsInfo.map { it.index }
        }
    }
}
LazyColumn(
    state = state,
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(30.dp)
) {
    items(100) { index -> 
        val isVisible by remember(index) {
            derivedStateOf {
                fullyVisibleIndices.contains(index)
            }
        }
        Text(
            index.toString(),
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(if (isVisible) Color.Green else Color.Transparent)
                .padding(30.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution would only work if you have homogeneous list, with all items same, but this won't work if you have heterogeneous list with multiple `items()` inside same LazyColumn.

Comment: @KinjalRathod this solution doesn't depend on item size/type so should work fine with any type of content. But you have to calculate relative item index if you have multiple `item`/`items` calls, that's the only API `LazyColumn` has

Comment: @PhilDukhov This solution has the performance issue you noted. How can this be done at the item level? I am trying to pause video when it scrolls past the visible area.

Comment: interesting. wouldn’t it still lead to a full lazy list re compositions. I will try and let you know.

Comment: @PhilDukhov : I still get an error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4`. It points to the line right after `val visibleItemsInfo = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo'. In my code, it is a `filter` operation on `visibleItemsInfo`. I think by the time the list is filtered/processed, the array has changed. We need something similar to `collectLatest`

Comment: @500865 can you reproduce crash with my code? if no you better create a separate question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite late answer but have a try of this library: [Visibility Tracker](https://github.com/hevinxx/visibility-tracker)
It detects the visibililty ratio changed even if you have nested lazy columns and rows.

```
VisibilityTracker(
    onVisibilityChanged = { isVisible ->
        if (isVisible) yourLogic()
    },
    treatOnStopAsInvisible = true
) {
    // Your composable content here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use offset of visible card

```
val currentVisibleIndex = remember {
                derivedStateOf {
                    val visibleItem = listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo

                    visibleItem.firstOrNull()?.index?.let { currentIndex ->
                        if (visibleItem.firstOrNull()?.offset!! == 0) {
                           currentIndex
                        } else if (visibleItem.firstOrNull()?.offset!! > LEFT_OFFSET) { //value should be checked based on your card size ex: -234 means card is partially visible on screen
                            if (currentIndex < list.size) {
                               currentIndex + 1
                            } else {
                               currentIndex
                            }
                        } else if (visibleItem.firstOrNull()?.offset!! > RIGHT_OFFSET){
                            if (currentIndex-1 >= 0) {
                               currentIndex - 1
                            } else {
                               currentIndex
                            }
                        } else {
                            currentIndex
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

You can check the LEFT and RIGHT_OFFSET values through log based on your card size.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to pause a video when it's just out of the screen?
These allow view components not to worry about a list(container).
To implement this you should add `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.7.+`

```
LifecycleResumeEffect(Unit) { onPauseOrDispose { viewModel.pause() } }
```

However, if you have several video in a screen together, how to properly pause  one and keep another one - this is still an open topic