# Finding the middle visible item in LazyRow

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I have a scrollable LazyRow that contains numbers, I want for the middle visible number to
be automatically selected as shown below:

[image]

How could I find the middle visible item in a LazyRow?

code:

```
@Composable
fun ScrollableAgeSelector(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    val numbers = (12..100).toList()

 
    LazyRow(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp)
    ) {
        items(numbers.size) { index ->
            val num = numbers[index]
            NumberItem(
                num = num,
                selectedNum = 22
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into `state.layoutInfo`, you can use that to know how many items are on the screen, therefore the middle item? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72415419/how-to-know-items-which-are-fully-visible-in-the-view-port-of-a-lazy-row-in-jetp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate which item is in the center.

Something like:

```
    val state = rememberLazyListState()
    LazyRow(state = state) {
        itemsIndexed(itemsList) { index, item ->
            MyItem(
                state,
                index,
                //content = 
            )
        }
    }
```

With:

```
@Composable
fun MyItem(state: LazyListState, index: Int, /* content */) {

    val borderColor by remember {
        derivedStateOf {

            val layoutInfo = state.layoutInfo
            val visibleItemsInfo = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
            val itemInfo = visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull { it.index == index}

            itemInfo?.let {

                val delta = it.size/2 //use your custom logic
                val center = state.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset / 2
                val childCenter = it.offset + it.size / 2
                val target = childCenter - center
                if (target in -delta..delta) return@derivedStateOf Red
            }
            Transparent
        }
    }

    Box(
        Modifier
            .padding(4.dp)
            .width(65.dp)
            .height(120.dp)
            .background(Yellow)
            .border(1.dp, borderColor),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ){
        //content
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, what if I want to add empty items before and after the LazyRow, what should I change to keep highliting the centred item?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could use: `LazyListLayoutInfo`

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListLayoutInfo#visibleItemsInfo()

```
val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    // Provide it to LazyColumn
    LazyColumn(state = listState) {
        // ...
    }
```

You can get the `visibleItemsInfo` from the `listState`. `visibleItemsInfo` is a List containing information about each visible item.

i.e. calling `first()` on the list would give you the index of the first visible item, and calling `last()` can get you the last visible item.

Then you get the item index off each of these items using `index()`:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListItemInfo#index()

You can use that information to know the positional index of the item in the middle.

Comment: Thank you! Any idea how to keep scrolling after it reaches the end and the beginning?

Comment: If you know how many items need to be on screen for full width, you could add some blank items to the beginning and end? :-)

Comment: I mean I want to wrap around when it reaches the beginning or the end, so if we have 0-50 you can scroll after 50 which is 0 and vice versa

Comment: something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66503121/how-to-create-a-circular-endless-lazycolumn-lazyrow-in-compose